# FFMPEG options frame-for-frame input to output

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding

I have a set of numbered png images in a and I want to use ffmpeg to create a video from them. I have been able to do this but the problem is that the frame rate of the input is not the same as the out.

I've noticed that some frames are skiped and some are seen twice. The options I am using are

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i input%04.png -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 10 output.mp4
```

I want the output to the same frame-for-frame as the input. Which options will do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `fps` instead of `-r`

The command will become :

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i input%04.png -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=10,format=yuv420p" output.mp4
```

Reference : https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images